# How to override plugin Email template in CakePHP 3.x?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have followed the documentation, I copied the Email templates from the plugin's directory and pasted them in a new path in the main app's template path:

```
main_app/src/Template/Plugins/MyPLuginName/Email/new.ctp
```

I've modified the new.ctp with some dummy text to show that it is picking up from the overriding template and not the plugin one.  However, when I run the sequence, the email is the plugin's template.

I have previously managed to do this with CakeDC users plugin, but not email templates.  Can someone confirm if it is possible to override plugin Email templates?  This would help narrow down my troubleshooting...

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: [It's `Plugin`, not `Plugins`](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#overriding-plugin-templates-from-inside-your-application).

Comment: Oh god.....No... Please.... Yes... Yes it is Plugin and not Plugins....

Comment: can you add it as an answer?